# Firebase 3 permission denied after first-time sign-in with Google, works after second time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a Google sign-in implemented according to instructions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase 
Authentication and sign-in work fine, the user is authenticated and signed-in and the listener is called:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
```

However, when trying to read from a user node/path having a standard security rule:

```
  "users": {
     "$user_id": {
       ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $user_id",
       ".write": "auth !== null"
     }
  }
```

with the following code triggered later manually:

```
DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
userRef.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {
                 ...
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Log.w(TAG, "fb sync onCancelled: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

`onCancelled` is called with "permission denied". The `uid` is correct, equals to the user ID as returned by `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()`

Now the important part is that **everything works fine if I sign-out and sign-in again, or if I terminate and re-launch the app**. So I guess something must be wrong with the FirebaseAuth state after the initial sign-in, or maybe I miss something again..?

Tested with `firebase-*:9.0.2` and `play-services-auth:9.0.2` as well as `9.2.0`.

Comment: Can you show a complete minimal sample of how it fails? For example: when do you set the value of `uid`? When do you attach the listener? Creating such an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a great chance to isolate the problem, and makes it easier for us to help.

Comment: it looks good from here. Requires more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from Mr Frank I've managed to pinpoint the culprit. **The problem occurs when the user signs in with Google while being already signed in anonymously** (which I didn't take into account). So a workaround would be to sign out the anonymous user (`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().sign_out()`) before trying to sign in with Google, although I believe it's still undesired behavior, because it makes linking accounts problematic.

Here's an example to reproduce the problem:

```
public class TestAuthGoogle extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    static private final String TAG = TestAuthGoogle.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        signInAnonymously();

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                signInGoogle();
            }
        },5000);
    }


    void signInAnonymously() {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    void signInGoogle() {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.my_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(TestAuthGoogle.this)
                .enableAutoManage(TestAuthGoogle.this, TestAuthGoogle.this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
                Log.d(TAG,"Authenticated");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG,"Authentication failed");
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Signed in");
                            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    readFromDatabase();
                                }
                            },5000);
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    void readFromDatabase() {
        Log.d(TAG,"read from db");
        DatabaseReference uRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        uRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "fb onDataChange: " + data.getValue());
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "fb onCancelled: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onConnectionFailed");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**My observations with Firebase realtime database.**

> It caches data on server side before adding to database (for a few milliseconds).
>
> > Result:
> >
> > > Read operations are few milliseconds faster than write operations.

- What's happening with your request:

  - It reaches server and asks for data which is still not available in realtime database.
- Why that so:

  - because its cached and still to be added to realtime database.
  - all this caching and adding data to realtime database takes only milliseconds of time, but its significant when you immediately invoke data after adding because your **Get Data** request has reached the server before the node is created.
  - That's why it shows permission denied.
- When this does not happen:

  - When your device is using low speed internet connectivity, your request reaches Firebase server with a delay of 1-3 seconds, this happens naturally. So this problem will not arise there.
- What to do now:

  - Just introduce a delay of 2-3 seconds before requesting data for the first time.
  - This gives the whole operation of authentication, node creation and adding data enough time to complete.
  - Everything will be smooth from there.

Comment: feel free to comment if you need more help.

Comment: The time interval between sign-in and data request is longer than 2-3 seconds. The request is triggered manually and i have tried it even a few minutes after sign-in, it's permission denied, works only after re-launch or re-sign-in..